# How to get "public_content" permission in Instagram API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have App what use in my website a widget by [inwidget.ru](http://inwidget.ru) : this widget show recent photos by special user or hashtag (people who have red heads and use #redpeopleorg in Instagram will show in my website http://redpeople.org).

After 17'November 2015 Instagram had change rules.

I made a screencast, send submission with description why I need live-mode and tried to get "public_content" permission in Instagram API, but they changed review status to "Declined".

Anybody have positive experience with reviewing applications in Instagram Api?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @infused but it is "instagram-api" theme. How I can programming my app without permissions?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know devs who had. Bat there's still a hope, e.g. you can parse public search results: 
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/hashtag/

I use a bunch of javascript code, that contains json string with all posts - just json_decode'd it.

Comment: Didn't know that page existed, good looking. You care to share any scripts that support pagination from that page? Not sure how to trigger/capture the load more button's json.